# VB.Net CsvHelper class map

Tags: vb.net, linq, csv

I'm attempting to use the CsvHelper library to read a csv file in VB.Net however I'm having trouble mapping the rows to a custom class. How would I write the following piece of code in VB as opposed to C#

```
public sealed class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Id );
        Map( m = > m.Name );
    }
}
```

Code taken from the [library site](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-name)

Cheers, Connor

Comment: You need to show the main class (MyClass which is not a legal name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an object like this:

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

You can map it like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MyObjectMap
    Inherits CsvClassMap(Of MyObject)

    Sub New()
        Map(Function(x) x.Id)
        Map(Function(x) x.Name)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to Jeff's answer:

Assuming an object like this:

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

You can map it like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MyObjectMap
    Inherits CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap(Of MyObject)
    Sub New()
        Map(Function(x) x.Id)
        Map(Function(x) x.Name)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new version which I have (24.0.1) the below code will work for mapping of CsvHelper

```
Dim textReader As TextReader = File.OpenText(filename)

Dim config = New CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        config.Delimiter = ","
        config.MissingFieldFound = Nothing
        config.TrimOptions = True
        config.HeaderValidated = Nothing

Dim csv = New CsvReader(textReader, config)

csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(Of ModelMyObjectMap)()
```

Here a sample of map class

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property Handle As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property BodyHTML As String
    Public Property Vendor As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Tags As String

End Class

Public NotInheritable Class ModelMyObjectMap
    Inherits CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap(Of MyObject)

    Public Sub New()
        Map(Function(m) m.Handle).Name("Handle")
        Map(Function(m) m.Title).Name("Title")
        Map(Function(m) m.BodyHTML).Name("Body (HTML)")
        Map(Function(m) m.Vendor).Name("Vendor")
        Map(Function(m) m.Type).Name("Type")
        Map(Function(m) m.Tags).Name("Tags")
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you be more specific as to what has been changed and how one might work with the new version?

Comment: I just amend the answer, however, the important line is one line!